# Java Email: How to add Voting buttons in email, like "Yes" or "No"?

Tags: email

Can you please help me how to send email in JAVA where the email received should have Voting buttons, for example "Yes" or "No"?

Thanks,
Jemru-Da

Comment: A simple pointer, you need to send the email in text/html format, rest of the things will depend on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Hi Kal. Thanks for your reply however what I need is to send email with voting buttons without needing to go to the website anymore, just in the outlook voting email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [JTNEF](http://www.freeutils.net/source/jtnef/):

> Transport-Neutral Encapsulation Format (TNEF) is Microsoft's
>   non-standard format for encapsulating mail which has any
>   non-plain-text content or properties (such as rich text, embedded OLE
>   objects, voting buttons, and sometimes just attachments). Whether or
>   not a given message is encoded using TNEF is determined by the Outlook
>   default settings, per-recipient setting, Exchange Server settings, and
>   message type and content.

Comment: Hi npinti! Thanks for your reply. I agree with you. But I can't seem to find any good tutorial or example of it. Do you know tutorials or examples using JTNEF library? I would really appreciate. Thank you again.

Comment: @Jemru-Da: I have never used this API, there seems to be some sort of explanation on how/where you can find examples in the `How do I use the Java TNEF package?` section available on this page: http://www.freeutils.net/source/jtnef/#whatsnew

Comment: Hi npinti. Thanks for your reply, I know now that JTNEF.jar package can do that but there seems no available tutorial for it? Please if help me find a good tutorial. Thank you.

Comment: @Jemru-Da: I have given you a link which should be helpful. I have never used this library, and I simply pointed you to it.

Comment: okay. thanks. i had also emailed the author/support of the library but got to no reply yet. i think this is interesting library but there are not much tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Your voting buttons will be the links to a website where actual voting happens. Of course buttons will only be available in the HTML version of the email, the text version should fallback to simple textual links (For YES click here: http://blah...)

Comment: Hi maksimov. Thanks for your reply however what I need is to send email with voting buttons without needing to go to the website anymore, just in the outlook voting email.

Comment: @Jemru-Da I hope you didn't downvote me because you forgot to mention Outlook in your question.